# Sotware access to up-to-the minute SE data. Is it (a) possible (b) desirable (c) currently available?

Tags: support, data-explorer, data-dump, api

I'm an experienced computer programmer but new to data-mining.

I'd like to set up a bit of software to do a quick search on **current** SE information. Judging by other people's questions, I get the impression that the only data that we can get hold of is a dump that only gets updated infrequently.

For example, I'd like to write my own facility for finding current threads that interest me. (I know, some will say the present method is perfectly good. I'm just using this as an example).

What access do we or might we have to bang up-to-date information on SE? Information that we can access via software?

Comment: Use the [Stack Exchange API](http://api.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: There's an [API for Stack Exchange](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) if you need more current data than the Data Explorer

Comment: [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com) is being updated on a weekly basis, isn't it enough for you?

Answer (score 8):

> I get the impression that the only data that we can get hold of is a dump that only gets updated infrequently.

That is not true. [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) is updated every week. That is quite frequent in my opinion.

> What access do we or might we have to bang up-to-date information on SE? Information that we can access via sotware?

You can use the [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/) to create your own app. It is quite easy to set up. You just need to authenticate, and you can request the data using a REST API.

I have seen other users just scraping the front page (and extract the HTML elements out of it), but that seems the hard way to do it (and also the less preferred way).

Comment: and with scraping comes the throttling...I got myself IP-banned a lot by doing that...

Comment: Indeed. Have had that too.